# Change of variable for integrating a Dirac's delta function

Tags: dirac-delta

Consider this integral:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \delta(1-x^2)dx \quad .
$$
I tried to solve it by doing this change of variable:
$$
y = x^2  \\
dy = 2xdx 
$$
But I have got problems with the limits since both go to $1$, getting a meaningless integral. Any ideas to fix this?

Additionaly I was thinking that it isn't straightforward to extend the method for an integral of the type:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \delta(1-x^2 - y^2)dxdy \quad .
$$

Can you please give me a key to start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try splitting the integral, i.e.
$$\int_{-1}^1\delta(1-x^2)\,dx=\int_{-1}^0\delta(1-x^2)\,dx+\int_{0}^1\delta(1-x^2)\,dx$$
now deal with the integrals seperately, and the substitution may become meaningful. It didnt work before, since when you substitute over a domian, by setting $y=f(x)$, for some $f$, the function $f$ must be injective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=2(1-x)$.

$$
\int_{-1}^1\delta(1-x^2)\,dx=2\int_{0}^1\delta(1-x^2)\,= 2\int_{2}^0\delta\left(u(1-\tfrac{u}{4})\right)(-\tfrac{1}{2})\,du=\int_{0}^2\delta(u)du =\tfrac{1}{2}
$$
(using the symmetry of the delta function).